# How to make API calls. I am a beginner

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I want to make an app that shows a funfact/joke and there's a button that refreshes the activity to load another funfact/joke.

I have made the data class, retrofit object and the interface and made the layout and also have written some code in the main activity. The app runs, however the funfact/joke isn't loaded on the activity.

Please help, I am a beginner.

Here are the codes:

Data Class:

```
data class FunFact(
    val joke: String
)
```

Retrofit Object:

```
object RetrofitInstance {

    val api: FunFactInterface by lazy {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://geek-jokes.sameerkumar.website")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(FunFactInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
interface FunFactInterface {

    @GET("/api?format=json")
    suspend fun getFacts(): Response<FunFact>
}
```

Main Activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        GlobalScope.launch {
            loadData()
        }

    }


    private suspend fun loadData() {

        val dataApi = RetrofitInstance.api
        val results = dataApi.getFacts()
        if(results!=null){
            if (binding != null) {
                binding!!.textView.text= results.toString()
            }

        }
    }
}
```

XML Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="the fact"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Another Fact"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The XML Design is this:
[APP Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngm59.png)

Edit/Update: Thanks to you guys the app is getting response. I removed the keyword suspend from the functions and also added code to handle onFailure scenario. Also removed "val" before binding in mainActivity as suggested.

Updated Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var binding: ActivityMainBinding? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding!!.root)


        loadData()
        
        binding!!.button.setOnClickListener{
            loadData()
        }


    }


    private fun loadData() {

        val dataApi = RetrofitInstance.api
        var results = dataApi.getFacts()
        if (results!=null){

            results.enqueue(object: Callback<FunFact>{
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<FunFact>, response: Response<FunFact>) {
                    if(response!=null){
                        binding!!.textView.text= response.body().toString()

                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<FunFact>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Failure of response from API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            })

        }



    }
}
```

The app runs and the joke is loaded, the format of the joke is little different than desired. Any kind of help is truly appreciated.

**This is the image of the response that I got, I want to remove "funfact" and "joke=" :**
[image: the app image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code in `MainActivity` is correct, then you're not setting the value of the instance variable `binding` 'cause you're creating another local variable with the same name in the `Activity`s `onCreate`

Here's something you can do

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // set the value of the instance variable
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        GlobalScope.launch {
            loadData()
        }
    }


    private suspend fun loadData() = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val dataApi = RetrofitInstance.api
        val results = dataApi.getFacts()

        binding.textView.text = results.body()?.joke
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, by using GlobalScope without specifying Dispatchers.Main, they are trying to update a view off the main thread. `GlobalScope` should be replaced with `lifecycleScope` so it will be on `Dispatchers.Main.immediate` and it will be cancelled when the activity is closed. And the results line should catch exceptions to avoid any crash from failing to make connection to the API.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped. Can you see the new issue I am facing... How to format the response that I got?

Comment: @RudrankBasant I've updated my answer. I want to point out that what I've done is to make the project "work". They are more efficient ways of using coroutines and managing UI state in android. Here's [a code lab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines?hl=lt#0) to get you started on coroutines.

Comment: @TobiDaada thank you so much your solution worked. I am learning everyday thanks for helping. Really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not making a mistake you set everything up correctly however did not initiate the API call in your loadData method. You can do that by writing dataApi.getFacts().enqueue() inside enqueue you have to add Callback object as parameter. Maybe this link could be more helpful for you https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests

Instead of this

```
private suspend fun loadData() {

    val dataApi = RetrofitInstance.api
    val results = dataApi.getFacts()
    if(results!=null){
        if (binding != null) {
            binding!!.textView.text= results.toString()
        }

    }
}
```

Should be like this

```
private suspend fun loadData() {

        val dataApi = RetrofitInstance.api
        val results = dataApi.getFacts().enqueue(object: Callback<FunFacts>{
            override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<FunFacts>,
            response: Response<FunFacts>
                        ){
                // you can work with the response here
                if(results!=null){
                    if (binding != null) {
                        binding!!.textView.text= results.toString()
                    }

                }
            } override fun onFailure(call: Call<FunFacts>, t: Throwable) {
                // put code here when the call fails 
            }
        })
        
    }
```

Comment: Since OP is using a `suspend` function, there is no need to `enqueue` the request

Comment: Thanks for reply this really helped and worked. I learned so much today. Can you see the new issue I am facing?